EF Core - Multitenancy using a dynamic global filter
I'm trying to implement multitenancy in an app with a single database. I introduced a middleware that fetches the TenantId per request and a global filter to modelbuilder that filters all relevant entities by TenantId.
My problem is that the value of TenantId = tenantAccessor.TenantId is not dynamically set per http request but instead the filter with the default TenantID value of 0 is applied once during model creation.
    public static ModelBuilder AddTenantQueryFilter(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ITenantAccessor tenantAccessor)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (typeof(TenantBaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
            {
                var method = typeof(TenantsExtension)
                    .GetMethod(nameof(GetTenantFilter), System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
                    .MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType);

                var filter = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { tenantAccessor });
                entityType.SetQueryFilter((LambdaExpression)filter);
            }
        }
        return modelBuilder;
    }

    private static LambdaExpression GetTenantFilter<TEntity>(ITenantAccessor tenantAccessor) where TEntity : TenantBaseEntity
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = e => e.TenantId == tenantAccessor.TenantId;
        return filter;
    }

This is my current filter. What do i need to change that my filter applies/uses the requests current TenantId value?
The rest of the implemantation works. The middleware gets called and sets the TenantId correctly for each request and the filter also works if i set it manually to an existing TenantId when the model gets created.
That is another filter implementation i tried but same problem:
    public static ModelBuilder AddTenantQueryFilter(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ITenantAccessor tenantAccessor)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (typeof(TenantBaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
            {
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
                var property = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(TenantBaseEntity.TenantId));
                var constant = Expression.Constant(tenantAccessor.TenantId);
                var body = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);

                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(lambda);
            }
        }
        return modelBuilder;
    }


We can't help without the implementation of ITenantAccessor. Provided DbContext is registered as a scoped service (as it should) a new one is created for every HTTP request and should be able to check who the tenant is. BTW the multitenancy docs use EntityTypeBuilder.HasQueryFilter to set the filter when configuring the type, not SetQueryFilter to modify the completed model's types.

Try to isolate the problem. Does filtering work if you follow the doc example, using .Entity<ThatEntity>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == tenantAccessor.TenantId); for all entities? If it does, you know the problem isn't ITenantAccessor but something else, probably the reflection code. This will help you isolate the problem.

DbContext is registered as scoped service.
I didn't try with every single entity but it works with every entity i tried.
So i could manually write down
.Entity().HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == tenantAccessor.TenantId);
for every single relevant entity but i would prefer a solution where i don't have to write down every single entity but could base it on entities based on TenantBaseEntity.

I tried another filter with HasQueryFilter but have the same problem with tenantId (0) only being set when the model gets created (I added the filter it to the original post).

The "other" filter implementation is essentially the same as the original and doesn't demonstrate anything. You have to use normal  .Entity<ThatEntity>().HasQueryFilter first to isolate the problem. Is it the reflection code or the implementation of ITenantAccessor? You don't know, and we can't guess.

I used it with several entities in my DBContext file and it works:
....
modelBuilder.Entity()
.HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == _tenantAccessor.TenantId);
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
...

It doesn't work if add the exact same code to my modelbuilder extension and use it with modelBuilder.AddTenantQueryFilter(_tenantAccessor) though:
    public static ModelBuilder AddTenantQueryFilter(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ITenantAccessor tenantAccessor)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserEntity>()
            .HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == tenantAccessor.TenantId);
        return modelBuilder;
    }

Same problem that it doesn't use the current tenantId only the default value of 0 when creating the model.

That's probably because the expression used in HasQueryFilter isn't the same as that produced by your code. You're using a constant value, which I suspect is 0 when the lambda is generated. In .HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == tenantAccessor.TenantId) though, tenantAccessor is captured as a variable so when the query is generated, the current TenantID value is retrieved. Have you tried debugging the code to see what the TenantID value is when you build the expression?

BTW check Multi-tenant Apps With EF Core and ASP.​NET Core to see how not smart the tenant code is. It doesn't try to detect the tenant through eg the HttpContext on the fly. A middleware detects the tenant value and essentially passes it as a constant to the DbContext. It's always better to start with simple solutions and then try to make them smarter

Your solution has two issues:

Query filters can only utilize properties directly accessible from the DbContext.
The OnModelCreating method is invoked only once per DbContext class, making your tenantAccessor parameter ineffective.

Let’s consider the following implementation of a DbContext descendant, which addresses these concerns:
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ITenantAccessor? TenantAccessor { get; set; }

    public int? TenantId => TenantAccessor?.TenantId;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Entity configuration

        modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilter<TenantBaseEntity>(e => e.TenantId == TenantId);
    }    
}

In this example, I've utilized my extension method ApplyQueryFilter, which simplifies the application of such filters.
Here, TenantId is a property of the DbContext, satisfying the first requirement. The TenantAccessor property can be set via Dependency Injection or middleware, so the fact that OnModelCreating is called only once is not a concern.

Thanks a lot.
My accessor was already correctly implemented but using your query filter solved the problem. So if i understand correctly the main reason the ApplyGlobalQueryFilter method works during runtime is because the filter is passed as an Expression<Func<TBaseEntity, bool>> and not a fixed filter like in my approaches?

Problem that tenantAccessor instance is captured as a constant and EF Core always use this one instance as parameter.  When you pass in filter DbContext's property, the same capturing appear, but EF Core makes specil Expression preparation for DbContext properties to resolve this capturing. That's why you should only reference DbContext properties in filter.
